# Excel, modificar dados de linhas duplicadas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Boa tarde galera.

Sou muito ruim de Excel e apareceu uma demanda para mim que fazer manualmente dará uma mão de obra monstruosa, então venho até vocês.

Eis o cenário.

```
    A     | B   | C  |
1-  Tiago |     |    |
2-  Tiago | ok  |    |
```

Tenho que passar esse ok da celular B2 para a célula C1, e depois disso excluir a linha dois, visto que essa em minha tabela se trata de um dado duplicado.

Usei esse exemplo, porem na tabela que estou em mãos tenho mais de 10 mil linhas, alguém poderia me ajuda ?

Comment: O dado duplicado estaria somente na coluna A ou em mais colunas? Pode haver mais de duas linhas com o mesmo registro?

Comment: Em mais colunas, dados duplicados sao nome, tel e DDD, tenho somente duas linhas com o mesmo registro.